# Input Functions in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake, conways-game-of-life

I am building an example Workflow in snakemake, the Game of Life. In this particular example, I am using a starting grid that leads to an empty world after a few iterations. I would like to build a conditional workflow that checks for emptiness after each time step and stops the calculation of new time steps once the world is empty. It should then proceed to render a video from the displays of previous time steps.

To check for emptiness, I am using an input function and a checkpoint. Here is the Snakefile:

```
configfile: "config_exercise_2.yaml"
workdir: "../"

import numpy as np

Time = 1
def gridEmpty():
    global Time
    with open(checkpoints.CalculateNextTimeStep.get(time=Time).output[0],"rb") as f:
        if np.all(np.load(f) == 0): #grid is empty, no more timesteps required
            return [f"pictures/picture_t-{i}.jpg" for i in range(0,Time+1,1)]
        else: #grid is not empty, more timesteps required
            Time += 1
            checkpoints.CalculateNextTimeStep.get(time=Time)
                                                  
rule RenderVideo:
    input:
        gridEmpty
    output:
        "video/clip.mp4"
    params:
        framerate = config["FrameRate"]
    shell:
        "cat {input} | ffmpeg -framerate {params.framerate} -f image2pipe -i - {output}"
        
rule Displaytimestep:
    input:
        "arrays/array_t-{time}.npy"
    output:
        "pictures/picture_t-{time}.jpg"
    conda:
        "../environment/environment.yaml"
    params:
        timeStep = lambda wildcards: wildcards.time
    script:
        "../scripts/DisplayTimeStep.py"
    
checkpoint CalculateNextTimeStep:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: f"arrays/array_t-{int(wildcards.time)-1}.npy"
    output:
        "arrays/array_t-{time}.npy"
    params:
        GridSize = config["GridSize"]
    conda:
        "../environment/environment.yaml"
    script:
        "../scripts/CalculateNextTimeStep.py"
```

I remember that this code worked previously, however now I am getting

> Error:   TypeError: gridEmpty() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was
> given Wildcards:
>
> Traceback:

Which puzzles me, since I do not see where any arguments are given to the input function. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a function as input, like:

```
rule RenderVideo:
    input:
        gridEmpty
```

snakemake automatically calls the function using the `wildcards` object as argument to the function. That is, it calls `gridEmpty(wildcards)`. Since your definition of `gridEmpty` does not take any parameter, you get the error you see.

The easiest solution may be to define `gridEmpty` so that it takes one argument even if that argument is not used. Alternatively, this should also work and it is equivalent:

```
rule RenderVideo:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: gridEmpty(),
```

(NB: I haven't checked whether the rest of your code is correct)